# Hibernate for stored procedure access

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

We have business restriction in accessing the database only through stored procedure calls. Caching is also not allowed. Is there value in using Hibernate framework where in you are not using the features like building object relationship based complex queries or caching? We are using considering using the lightweight jdbc option.

Comment: Would you provide insight into why your company imposes this restriction? For instance, if it is for performance reasons, you can argue that Hibernate (actually, your connection pool) caches PreparedStatements, which mitigates this concern.

Comment: The database serves as a backup facility on distributed system for a DB residing on mainframe. All access to mainframe DB is based on stored procedures written in COBOL. So access to backup facility wehn needed must mimic the real access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate makes sense if you're going to map objects to tables.  I don't see how HQL can benefit you otherwise.

I would look into JDBC or Spring JDBC instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate's lazy loading and entity mapping still brings a lot of value to the table. I would go for it.